# In which way is a commented line active in a program file?

Tags: command-line, files, command

To solve the bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/127372) the solution seems to be commenting, not just adding a certain line in a file - as explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1028993&p=6951422#post6951422) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1028993&p=11716227#post11716227).

That is - to make that bug disappear in Xfce, a certain line has to be added. But as that is not enough, the suggested solution is to comment that very line.

I have the impression that the solution works. Is that placebo?

How come a line is necessary, but also has to be commented, that is - deactivated?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to i) ADD a new line and ii) comment the SAME line out? The posts you link to just say that the line should be commented, not added and then commented.

Comment: @terdon: sorry. i didn't understand the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/127372). i though that the line in the gtkrc-2.0 file was the solution, when that was the very bug. so, the solution [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1028993&p=6951422#post6951422) is to comment out that line:"I've only tried values from 0-2 with no success and finally I've comment it out". only that in my case the line was absent in the file. as a solution in this case would be possibly to add that line not in order to comment it, but to set a value above 51

Comment: If the line was absent, yours is probably another bug. Alternatively, perhaps the line is present in a system-wide conf file and that's the one you'll need to comment out.

Comment: @terdon - about 70 according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/127372/comments/3) or above 51 according to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunar/+bug/127372/comments/5).  i have a bug that is similar but different. i will try to report it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are commenting a line in a configuration file.  Really, it would be working around a bug of some sort.  In other words, having the line in the configuration file activates the broken code.  Commenting it out in the configuration file leaves the broken code dormant, and things work again.

It only fixes it from the user perspective.  The user thinks the bug is "fixed" because their program works again.  But really, it is just a workaround.